# JQuery AJAX $.post() doesn't works

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

the function than i use in my work

```
$(function(){
    $('#group2').change(function(){
        var url='jtsprocess2.php'; 
        var dataSet={ go2: $('#group2').val() }; 
        $.post(url,dataSet,function(data){
            //alert(data);
            $('#all6').html(data); 
         });
    });
});
```

i call out at tag :

```
<table border='0' width='1000' cellpadding='5' celspacing='2' bgcolor='#000000'>
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCFF'>
        <td colspan='3'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="etc"> <b>pls input</b> <input name="etctext" id="Text1" type="text" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; group
<select name="group2" id="group2" class="chosen-select" onchange='Checkgroup(this.value);'>
<?php
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jts_group", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
?>
 <?php
  echo "<option value=''>choose</option>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
       {
          echo "<option value='".$row['Job_Group_No']."'>".$row['Job_Group_Name']."</option>";
       }
 ?>
 <option value='other'>other</option>
</select> 
 <input type="text" name="group6a" id="siteetc" style='display:none'  placeholder='pls input'/>

        </td>
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCFF' id='all6'>
          <td>
             place 1
    <select name="site13" id="Select13" class="chosen-select" style="width:150px">
    <option value='' >pls choose</option>
    </select> 
            </td>
            <td>
          place #2
    <select name="site14" id="Select14" class="chosen-select" style="width:150px">
    <option value=''>pls choose</option>
    </select> 
            </td>
            <td>
            place #3
    <select name="site15" id="Select15" class="chosen-select" style="width:150px">
    <option value=''>pls choose</option>
    </select> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

it send databack to first page and replace with select option but when i submit form it doesn't go.
other value in form go but not this function.

ps.I new here and i begin to learn code about week.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question/issue...

Comment: What is `#group2` referring to? The markup snippet doesn't include an `id="group2"`.

Comment: i copy only example for my code because it too much to put in for question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.Note the quotes around the key.

```
 var dataSet=Json.Stringify("{ `go2`
: $('#group2').val() }");
```

Comment: it doesn't work . there is a chance than code doesn't because other javascript or jquery .

Comment: i found out the error in hit with other tag ex. as<div> <headed>